# Making grandchild of root null , the right way in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a multiway tree with the following code in C++. As of now, it is more like a sample piece of code.

I wish to do the following with this piece of code(and I am able to get the desired result):

1. Create a struct Node of two members : value(of the node) and array of children of the node.
2. Make 'root's value = 5
3. Make the children's values equal to 10,20,30 & 40
4. Make the children of children's values equal to null(=0);

I am getting the desired output , but **what I want to know is if I am doing it the right way.**

Thanks, in advance.

```
//multinode tree
#include<iostream>
#define null 0

struct Node
{
    int value;
    Node *child[4]; 
};

void display(Node *root){
    if(root==null)
        return;
    else{

        std::cout<<root->value<<" ";
        if(root->child[0]!=null)
            for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
            {
                if(root->child[i]!=null)
                    display(root->child[i]);

            }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node *root=new Node;
    Node *test=null;
    root->value=5;
    int values[]={10,20,30,40};
    int i=0;
    for (i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        Node *temp=new Node;
        temp->value=values[i];
        root->child[i]=temp;
        for (int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            root->child[i]->child[j]=null;
        }
        std::cout<<"Root value "<<root->child[i]->value<<"\n\n ";
    }
    std::cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n";
    display(root);

}
```

Comment: I've fixed the indentation on this code. There was some non-standard indentation that could confuse readers.

Comment: Also, "`#define null 0`"? What's wrong with `NULL`?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very C like approach and you are using C++ so take advantage of that fact.

1. Get rid of the `#define` and use `nullptr` keyword instead.
2. Name member variables something special such as `m_` so `Node *m_children[4]`;
3. Try use C++ data structures instead of arrays and `char*` so `vector<Node*>` children.
4. Make the `Node` struct into a class and write getters and setters to encapsulate the new vector structure you should use.
5. Encapsulate the `void display(Node *root)` function into a class such:

   ```
   class Tree
   {
       Tree(int depth);// create a tree with x depth
       etc...
       void display();
   public:
       Node* m_root;
   };
   ```

   You could create some functionality to able to initialise the tree with some custom data structure.
6. Add the following code in main into the tree class

   ```
   for (i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
       Node *temp=new Node;
       temp->value=values[i];
       root->child[i]=temp;
       for (int j=0;j<4;j++)
       {
           root->child[i]->child[j]=null;
       }
       std::cout<<"Root value "<<root->child[i]->value<<"\n\n ";
   }
   ```

PS. Sorry if the code doesn't work; I'm at work and have no way to check it!

Comment: Additionally you might want to add into the Node struct another Node* to its parent so you can reverse navigate the tree also.

Comment: #2 is a style choice, not necessarily C++ mandated..

Comment: #2 http://www.devx.com/cplus/10MinuteSolution/35167
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1488.pdf

Its a bad approach if you are using C++ instead of C.
There is a keyword for very good reasons.

Comment: I was talking about the `m_` prefix, I have nothing against `nullptr`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake yes your right it is a style choice. But any similar style choice is good. I'm just highly recommending for the same reason we dont call everything "a", "b", "c" or writing our code on 1 line or just having 1 file with everything.

Comment: Thanks you. Yes, I realize that the style of the program is very much C-like, but I want to better my ability to manipulate the more fundamental aspects , first. At this point, I am unable to adapt to the genuine C++ style of programming, but I will adopt C++ fully, once I find adequate time.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct enough.

You could improve it in a couple of ways,

- if you do `new Node()`, note the additional `()`, [its members will be zero initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/620402/1520364), so you can skip the `null`ing of the children.
- you can add a constructor which initializes among other things the arrays to `null`, so that you don't need to remember to do it every time, Recommended for readability and future proof as commenters suggest?

Comment: The standard does not require default initialisation of members, so your first advice is dangerous.

Comment: @CongXu I am going based on [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/620402)

Comment: @KarthikT: I think it's dangerous to rely on that behavior. What happens if someone unwittingly adds a new member to the `Node` class which makes it non-POD?

Comment: @NikBougalis correct me if I am wrong, but it looks to me like the link promises 0 initialization as long as there is no user defined constructor. Regardless, I would go the explicit route (#2) myself.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was specifically wondering if **root->child[i]->child[j]=null;** was a prudent way to initialize the grand-children of root to null.

Comment: @RahulRajaram imo, the right way is that they be `null` by default instead of having to do it manually, safer that way, you cant forget.